# How can I run Client-Server python program in macbook terminal?

Tags: python, sockets, terminal

Can anyone tell me the steps to run a python socket program in macbook terminal which has the requirement:

```
Usage: %s <Host> <Port>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I presume you already have the program on your MacBook and you just need to run it.

Firstly you need to be in the directory that has the program in it.

- Open terminal
- Change to the correct directory with cd. For example, if it is in a folder called 'Test' on your desktop you would type `cd Desktop/Test/`
- You can then check the content of the directory by typing `ls`. Your program.py should appear in the list returned by the command.

To run the program:

- `%s` means that it is taking a String as one of the input arguments
- 'Host' would be the IP address of the host machine. This will be in the format 123.456.789.123
- 'Port' is the associated port for that service on the host machine. For example 9876

For example, you have a basic program called simpleMessage.py that transmits a simple message, in our case "Hello World", to a server hosted locally on your network with the host address of 192.168.0.1 and the associated port of 5050 you would write this:

```
python simpleMessage.py "Hello World" 192.168.0.1 5050
```